# listbox scrollbar not visible when item height is too big

Tags: silverlight, listbox, scrollbar

I have a stackpanel of height 100 and I have a Listbox inside the stackpanel.
The Listbox has items which are bigger than 100 in height (150 for example).

The listbox's scrollbar in this case as the a single item itself is taller than the actual height of the stackpanel.

How do we get the scrollbar to comeup in this situation.

Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

The StackPanel does not constrain the child ListBox height. It is just clipping it.

Use a grid instead or constrain the ListBox to the same height as the StackPanel. Stretching child controls to a StackPanel (in the direction of *StackPanel-growth*) does not work.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I didnt try your option as I actually ended up using a TreeView instead which has a built in scrollbar feature. TreeView worked for the UI we were looking for. Thanks again.